# Pointer incrementation causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-arithmetic

This code causes a segmentation fault when running. It's due to the odd pointer incrementation, but I don't understand why this is a problem, as it seems to make sense.

I think it should: increment the pointer, then dereference the unincremented pointer, then increment the value 10 to 11. So out = 11, and the first value in the array is now 11. So this loop should print out 11, 21, 31, 1, then go on infinitely printing out values outside the array. This is clearly bad practice but we just want to see why this double pointer incrementation isn't valid.

My code:

```
int main() {
     int myarray[4] = {10,20,30,0};
     int *p = myarray;
     int out = 0;
     while (out = ++(*p++)) {
         printf("%d ", out);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you assume that ++(*p++) increments the number first and then the pointer?

Comment: I never said that it did....

Comment: Well you assume the result should be 11, 21, 31, 1 and not 10, 21, 31, 1. Can rephrase the question as well. "Why would you assumed that the increment of the array contents increments on a non incremented pointer?"

Comment: Because the pointer is incremented. First, *p++ increments the pointer and returns the unincremented value. So it returns 10. Then ++(..) increments it to 11.

Comment: The increment is valid; the code is the same as `for (int i = 0; myarray[i] != -1; ++i) { printf("%d ", ++myarray[i]); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop never terminates:

First iteration:

```
*p = 10, out = 11
```

Next iteration:

```
*p = 20, out = 21
```

Next iteration:

```
*p = 30, out = 31
```

Next iteration:

```
*p = 0, out = 1
```

Next iteration:

You are accessing unauthorized memory, which leads to undefined behavior.

**Update**

After the last item from the array is accessed, the part of the stack frame that contains code gets trampled over by the increment operator. Hence, the code cannot be expected to behave in a logical manner.

Comment: Then why don't we see the first output before it gets into out of array bounds? It just says segmentation fault and nothing is outputted.

Comment: @user2666425, That's the nature of undefined behavior. You can't expect anything to be logical.

Comment: @R Sahu, in other test cases, we can see it outputting the valid array values, then crazy random memory locations. I don't understand why it seems to detect a problem now at the beginning of the program.

Comment: @user2666425: The answer to that is probably buffering of `printf()`'s output.  Generally stdout is flushed on newlines when writing to a terminal (screen), otherwise the C standard library will wait for the buffer (typically 8KB or so) to fill up before it writes anything out.  Change the space to a `\n` and you should see the initial output before the crash.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That was spot on, dude. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @user2666425: You're welcome.  I've had *a lot* of experience with that problem...

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
while (out = ++(*p++))
```

The preincrement (the first "++") returns the incremented value. So when you reach the end of the array, it returns 1, which evaluates to `true`, and the loop keeps going.

Answer (score 1):

When `p` exceeds the range of `myarray`, `deference` causes undefined behavior.